# SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations error while trying to connect Impala with Table Desktop

Tags: impala

I need help for  this error on Cloudera Impala :

```
[Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (100) Error form the Impala Thrift API: SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations: error code: 0 .
```

Could anyone help me to solve and explain what does the error means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save a copy of the .pem certificate from the Impala server to the computer running Tableau Desktop.

Download and edit the TDC file to specify the file path to the trusted certificates, and then add the .tdc file to:

1. **Tableau Desktop**: The My Tableau Repository\Datasources folder.
2. **Tableau Server for Windows**: In the Tableau Server data directory
   under tabsvc\vizqlserver\Datasources. The default path is
   C:\ProgramData\Tableau\Tableau
   Server\data\tabsvc\vizqlserver\Datasources
3. **Tableau Server for Linux**: In the Tableau Server data directory under
   tabsvc/vizqlserver/Datasources. The default path is
   /var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/data/tabsvc/vizqlserver/Datasources/

For any changes to Tableau Server, changes must be applied to all nodes using processes that make data source connections (Backgrounder, Data Server, Vizportal, VizQL Server).

The TDC file must be an exact match to its counterpart on Tableau Desktop: the same drive letter, file path, and name for the .pem file.